Is there any malicious secure MPC protocol to compute the sum of values belong to different paties?
Suppose Alice,Bob,Charlie each has a value $a$,$b$,$c$, they want to obtain $a+b+c$ without disclosing their value. I wonder if it is a successful attack when a malicous adversary who corrput Alice modify $a$ with $a'$ during the  excution of the protocol.

In general when there are malicious adversaries we don't care about correctness, only about privacy
